# How do I migrate Digits to Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-digits

When I go through the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170822230635/https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/apple-migration.html) to migrate my app to Firebase, They give the following image to describe the migration's first step:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fabric.io](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/_images/digits-moving-firebase.png))</sub>

But I don't get this white pop up. I get [this view](https://ibb.co/dBy0Qv) without pop up instead. How do I migrate?

Comment: you must first go to https://www.fabric.io/login?redirect_url=%2F_

`Note`
`You need to be an Admin within the Fabric organization to start the linking.`

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis I am an Admin, I do get a warning in orange saying Digits is moving to Firebase, but I am not able to find "Start migration to Firebase" option, I don't have enough rep to post an image so I can't show you.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. There is a small subset of apps that won't have access to the migration currently, but we're working on making that possible for all. Stay tuned!

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks for your answer, can you tell me in how much time will it be possible for us to do so? Is there a possiblity that I won't be able to migrate my application to Firebase at all?

Comment: I don't have a firm date yet, but it's something we're actively working on.

Comment: This might help: 
[Migrate your iOS App from Digits to Firebase]
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/digits-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Digits migration was not working, I started using the Firebase Auth for my app.