# Digits migration to Firebase is not enabled for my account

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I am unable to add Digits to our iOS app nor migrate to Firebase auth.  The "Start migration to Firebase" as described in https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/apple-migration.html is not enabled for my account.  I am an admin and I see the note to "Digits is moving to firebase" with an exclamatory symbol beside Digits in Fabric.  Can you please help enable the migration or let us add Digits if the option to migrate to Firebase is still a WIP?

Thanks!

Comment: I see another similar question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062567/how-do-i-migrate-digits-to-firebase, so it looks like more than myself is affected at the moment.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. There is a small subset of apps that won't have access to the migration currently, but we're working on making that possible for all. Stay tuned!

Comment: @MikeBonnell, thanks.  Any ETA by when the migration option can be enabled?  If there are delays with Firebase Auth, can Digits be allowed in the interim?  Having access to neither is blocking us at the moment.

Comment: We're working on making it available for all apps as quickly as possible. Firebase Auth is available now for iOS and Web. Android is coming soon.

Comment: > Firebase Auth is available now for iOS 
@MikeBonnell, I am somewhat confused -- is firebase auth supposed to be available for *all* iOS apps at the moment or is it generally available for most iOS apps and you will still need to flip the switch for some iOS apps?  Mine is an iOS app and firebase auth is not available and Digits is deprecated.

Comment: Alternatively, if I were to delete my iOS app from fabric and re-add it, would I get an option to migrate to firebase auth immediately?  If so, I am happy to do that, so I can get access to using Digits immediately.

Comment: Firebase Auth is available for all iOS apps. Migrating from Digits to Firebase Auth is available to most apps on Digits. If you don't want to migrate your userbase, then you can add Firebase Auth now. Adding Digits to new apps is no longer possible.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I don't really need any migration as this is a new app and don't have any users at the moment.  I was waiting for the migration option to be enabled for no real reason.  Let me start using firebase auth right away.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I'd recommend making that the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I didn't need to do any *migration* at all as mine is a new iOS app and don't have any userbase to migrate.  This means that I can right away start using Firebase SDK and thus it's auth component.